# Merging two backbone.js collections (outer join)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two large JSON vars with lots of data in it which each represents a collection.

Since both have similar attributes for each object inside each JSON, I would like to make an outer join, thus same attributes will stay only adding attributes which aren't in both (no duplicates)

```
var json1 = JSON.parse([{ name: "test_user1", id: 0102 }]
var json2 = JSON.parse([{ name: "test_user2", email: "someemail@gmail.com"}]
```

Merging both as I want should produce:

```
 [{ name: "test_user2", email: "someemail@gmail.com", id: 0102}]
```

Think as json1 and json2 has both the same number of objects inside it
I would like to merge obj1 and obj1 from json1 and json2 together , obj2 and obj2 from json1 and json2 , etc...

Comment: Why test_user2 and not test_user1 in the result?

Comment: @Khnle-KevinLe it doesn't matter actualy

Comment: The title says you want "outer join", and in the question you mention you want "inner join".  Please take a moment to decide which one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially misread your problem, but using `at` should let you merge by index position.

```
collectionA.each(function (model, index) {
  model.set(collectionB.at(index).attributes);
});
```